# If reg key and value exist in batch

Tags: batch-file, registry

How can I check if reg key and value exist in a batch file and change the value if it exists.  Below is what I'm trying to do in English.

`HKCU\Software\App`

`IF "Directory" = "c:\users\%username%\AppData"
THEN change to "Directory" = "%userprofile%\AppData"
ELSE do nothing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See whether this works:

```js
@echo off & setlocal

reg query HKCU\Software\App /v Directory 2>NUL || (
    reg add HKCU\Software\App /v Directory /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%%userprofile%%\AppData"
)
```

See `reg query /?` and `reg add /?` in a cmd console for full details of syntax.

---

**Edit:** Restricting the creation of the reg value only if it exists and contains a specific location requires a bit more logic.  If the path contained in the registry contains a trailing backslash, or an inline dot, or has `%username%` expanded or not expanded, this can cause a simple string match to fail.  When comparing paths, it's a good idea to `cd` or `pushd` into the directory to ensure it's in a unified format, all relative directories are resolved, all variables expanded, trailing slash is stripped, etc.  Comparing the short filenames by using a `for` loop + `%%~sI` or similar is another option, but the `pushd` method has an added benefit of testing whether the directory exists and can be accessed.

```js
@echo off & setlocal

rem // proceed only if the App key exists in the registry
reg query HKCU\Software\App >NUL 2>NUL && (

    for /f "skip=2 tokens=2*" %%I in (
        'reg query HKCU\Software\App /v Directory 2^>NUL'
    ) do call pushd "%%~J" 2>NUL && (
        rem // call pushd "%%~J" ensures the dir exists and the location is normalized

        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        if /i "!CD!"=="C:\Users\%username%\AppData" call :regupdate
        endlocal

        popd

    rem // if pushd failed, the path is invalid.  Update it.
    ) || call :regupdate
)

exit /b

:regupdate
reg add HKCU\Software\App /v Directory /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%%userprofile%%\AppData" /f
```

One other note: `%appdata%` and `%localappdata%` might be preferable to `%userprofile%\AppData` depending what you intend to do with the value once retrieved.  [See this page](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) for a full list of Windows environment variables.

Comment: The only thing about this is that it will create the key and value if it doesn't exists.  I need it to do nothing if it doesn't exists.  I only want to change the value if that specific key and value exists.  Thanks though.  Any other ideas?  :)